# Why are morning glory leaves becoming transparent?

Tags: morning-glory

It's growing good. Several vines have turned purple and the leaves yellow and not thriving. The only bug I found was a praying mantis. Morning glories are my fave and this is discouraging.  Also, no blooms at all.

Comment: Welcome! Do you have a photo or two of the plant and the damage? Can you [edit] your post with a few details about location, recent weather and your care routine? “Growing good” and “not thriving” seems a bit of a contradiction, can you clarify for us, please? As for all new users, I’d also recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say what is making your leaves transparent, sometimes the addition of iron will help with the coloring. Also, be happy that you found a praying mantis, as they are beneficial insects and good to have around!

Answer (score 1):

I guess [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/gardening/comments/cic01a/strange_grey_spots_on_morning_glory_leaves_anyone/) is what you perceive as "transparent", and the damage is caused by leaf miners. If the leaves has large areas with holes, then it is more likely a snail attack.

[image: Green, spade-shaped leaves with faint white splotching]

If it is more like [this](https://www.gardenstew.com/threads/what-is-wrong-with-my-morning-glory-leaves.38902/), then it is powdery mildew.

[image: Green, spade-shaped leaves with white regions]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about in morning glory, but in tomatoes, purple and sort-of-transparent (I'd say translucent, rather) leaves tend to mean sulfur-deficiency. That's a possibility here.

Purple leaves can also be caused by phosphorus-deficiency, cold weather, and I think even magnesium-deficiency. Yellow leaves can be caused by lots of different deficiencies (pretty much everything, but nitrogen is the usual suspect). Yellowing leaves can also be caused by disease.

Epsom salt has both sulfur (sulfate) and magnesium; it's easy to find and inexpensive; so, it might be worth a try to see if it helps. Phosphorus tends to help with blooms, if you're in need of phosphorus.